# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem I did all step to create keystores and how can I fix this error
[image]

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Failed to read key keystore01 from store "c:\Users\saydo\AndroidKeys\keystore01.jks": No key with alias 'keystore01' found in keystore c:\Users\saydo\AndroidKeys\keystore01.jks

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             12.6s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: you can just write : ./keystore01.jks instead of full path

Comment: where can I write it can you explain what do you mean?

Comment: in the file key.properties

Comment: I write : ./keystore01.jks only inside the storefile?

Comment: yes  instead of c:\Users\saydo\AndroidKeys\keystore01.jks

Comment: I did it but same problem so what I do to fix it

Comment: try this way .\keystore01.jks

Comment: I tried but same problem can you give me the best solution

Comment: Follow this doc : https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android  : check from this topic : Reference the keystore from the app